# Adding to a listbox in VB

Tags: vb.net, listbox

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim name As String = txtNames.Text
    For i = 0 To lstbxNames.Items.Count - 1
        If name = Str(lstbxNames.Items(i)) Then
            MsgBox("This name is already in the list.")
        Else
            lstbxNames.Items.Add(name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The item won't get added but it would if I put "lstbxNames.Items.Add(name)" at the top of the for statement.

Comment: What is the type of lstbxNames? What does lstbxNames.Items(i) return? What is its type? What do you get if you put a watch on that expression and trace your code?

Comment: Hello Robert,  lstbxNames.Items(i) should return every item in the list box, not sure what you mean by what's the type of lstbxNames, it's just a list box of vb. When I return the items from listbox I add "Str" which makes them type string.

Answer (score 0):

Your **FOR loop** has few issues. As I can see, you are inserting the same **name** multiple times and same for msg box. You can directly check a value already exist in list box before adding to it with **contains** method.

And you must check your textbox is not empty before adding it to list.

```
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim name As String = txtNames.Text
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) Then  
           if (!lstbxNames.Items.Contains(name)) Then
              lstbxNames.Items.Add(name);
          else
             MsgBox("This name is already in the list.");
        End If
    End Sub
```